# Сделать деструктор чистым виртуальным и не поймать ошибку на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++, ооп, полиморфизм

Ничего не понимаю, если сделать деструктор класса чистым виртуальным, то ничего, все хорошо, но, как только начнем наследоваться от данного класса, то будет ошибка на этапе компиляции, ошибка линкера **LNK2019**.

Оно то и понятно, что если определить или пометить деструктор как `default`, то все нормально, но если мне необходим именно чистый виртуальный деструктор?

https://ideone.com/F0h0do

Comment: Деструктор не может быть чисто виртуальным, он обязан иметь реализацию, так как будет в любом случае вызываться деструкторами классов, наследующих от данного

Comment: @VTT: Аааа, вот блин, я не посмотрел ассемблер код, там совсем нет определений для деструкторов если делать его чисто виртуальным. Добавьте как ответ.

Comment: @VTT: Деструктор действительно должен иметь реализацию, но это тем не менее не мешает ему быть чистой виртуальной функцией. По крайней мере в рамках формальной терминологии С++.

Comment: Что за терминология: "чистый виртуальный"? Вас же ни кто не поймет, да и вопрос в таком ключе бесполезный. Есть понятие - **абстрактный**, его и следует использовать. Говорите по-русски.

Comment: @mega, дословный перевод pure virtual. Не пойму что вас смутило.

Comment: Таким терминам не нужен дословный перевод. Да и тут, в первом же предложении явно проблема с этим дословным переводом: "... чисто виртуальным..." (да и в последнем - тоже). Тут большинство русскоговорящих программистов. Это как раз тот случай, когда дословный перевод не к месту.

Comment: @mega: Но абстактный класс, но не метод, верно?

Comment: [почему не метод-то?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Comment: @mega: С одной стороны, термин "абстрактный" в терминологии С++ уже занят: *абстрактным* является класс, содержащий чистые виртуальные функции. С другой стороны не совсем ясно, почему даже в английской терминологии не стали назвать "pure virtual" функции просто "abstract" функциями. В любом случае, это весьма спорный вопрос - стоит ли вносить рассогласование терминологий.

Comment: @AnT, с Вами даже википедия не согласна :) А терминологии нужно придерживаться все же понятной, русской. Для этого вопроса релевантный термин - абстрактный деструктор, а не чистый виртуальный деструктор.

Comment: @mega: Во-первых, вы о чем вообще? Прилинкованная вами страница Википедии со мной полностью согласна (читайте сами: "Абстра́ктный ме́тод (или чистый виртуальный метод..."). Во-вторых, мне не понятно ваше "даже". Википедии еще расти и расти до тех пор, пока ее несогласие со мной будет иметь какое-то значение.

Comment: Пардон, с "даже" - я пошутил, надо заменить на "ажно" :)

Comment: Думаю, мой посыл понятен: хотите, чтобы Вам помогли - пишите на русском, ну или английском (все Вас поймут), но не надо каверкать нормальную терминологию "дословными переводами".

Comment: Оооокей.... Дули нотед )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже когда вы делаете деструктор чистой виртуальной функцией, вы все равно должны предоставить определение для этого деструктора.

Чистые виртуальные функции нельзя вызвать через механизм *виртуального* (динамического) вызова, но это никак не запрещает вызывать эти же функции через механизм обычного прямого *невиртуального* (статического) вызова. Поэтому если у вас в программе есть *невиртуальные* вызовы некоей чистой виртуальной функции, то вам придется предоставить определение для этой функции.

Деструктор - как раз пример функции, которая в общем случае будет неявно вызываться и невиртуальным образом тоже. В частности, деструктор базового класса будет неявно вызываться из деструкторов классов-наследников, если таковые имеются. В вашем случае ошибка как раз и возникает, как только в программе появляются классы-наследники. Поэтому для деструктора всегда следует предоставлять определение.

Также стоит заметить, что в С++ определения чисто виртуальных функцией должны делаться *за пределами определения класса*, т.е. грамматика языка не позволяет "засунуть" в объявление функции одновременно и чистый спецификатор `= 0` и тело функции. Определение следует делать отдельно.